# C# why object can't be converted to int

Tags: c#

I have some problems with simply exercise.. I have to write a program that asks the user for the value of N and then calculates N! using recursion.
I wrote something like this:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This program will calculate a factorial of random number. Please type a number");
            String inputText = Console.ReadLine();
            int N = int.Parse(inputText);
            
            String outputText = "Factorial of " + N + "is: ";
            int result = Count(ref N);
            Console.WriteLine(outputText + result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static object Count(ref int N)
        {
            for (int N; N > 0; N++)
            {
                return (N * N++);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the problem is in line "int result = Count(ref N);"
I have no idea why it can't be converted to int.

Comment: `private static object` -- why did you choose that signature for the `Count` method? Specifically, why `object`?

Comment: You also shouldn't use `ref`.

Comment: I don't see any recursion here. Why titled as recursion?

Comment: Recursive functions are functions that call themselves.

Comment: This doesn't use recursion, `Count` shouldn't be returning `object` (it should be returning `int`), and you've named the parameter and the loop variable the same in `Count` (which `N` is being incremented in the loop? The one declared in the function parameter or the one declared as the loop counter?). I'd suggest scrapping this and starting over, beginning with a re-reading of what "recursion" means.

Answer (score 10):

because it is returning an object and object cannot be implicitly converted to int, what you can do though is to change the signature of your method like

```
private static int Count(ref int N)
```

or you can do this

```
int result = (int)Count(ref N);
```

**Take a simple example**

```
//this is what you are doing
object obj = 1;
int test = obj;   //error cannot implicitly convert object to int. Are you missing a cast?

//this is what needs to be done
object obj = 1;
int test = (int)obj; //perfectly fine as now we are casting

// in this case it is perfectly fine other way around
obj = test;  //perfectly fine as well
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its beceause your method type is "object", and it should be "int".

Answer (score -2):

Yes, as previous replies have mentioned, you don't need the ref, and you need to return an int. Your question says you need to use recursion, but you are using a for loop?

here's how you write a factorial recursive method:

```
public long Factorial(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)  //base
     return 1;
   return n * Factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: where did long come from?

Comment: Since this is obviously an assignment focused on creating a recursive function you probably shouldn't have just given astar the answer either.

Comment: @Sayse you dont need the long, a simple integer will do it, but considering Factorial can easily return values over someting times 10 to the power of 100. So I guess it isnt the worst choice